# Deploying an app with engine using git and local versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, rails-engines

I am trying to understand the workflow for deploying a rails engine. I read  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20720900/4017627). But I don't fully understand what is going on between Gemfile, bundler, Capistrano and rails.

I have a situation where I am working on an app locally pushing to a git repository and using Capistrano to deploy. In my apps Gemfile

```
#gem 'my_engine', git: "git@myrepo.com/myengine.git"
gem 'my_engine', path: '/local/path/to/MyEngine'
```

When I am developing I often comment out the git repository and use my local( I know some may take issue with this but another time another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12805569/4017627)) what I want to know is:

- when is the engine included or mounted?
- If I am working with the local engine and decide to deploy the app is the local engine included at this point?

  - Would the local current branch/state be what is used?
- If I decide to switch to the repo for production(and or dev) at what point is that included?
- Does Capistrano run bundle install during the deployment?

  - Would Capistrano be able to use my local copy or would it need me to use the git repo?

Answer (score 0):

Engine and Host application are in same repository then specifying

```
gem 'my_engine', path: '/local/path/to/MyEngine'
```

will work.

If you had different repository for engine and application then need specify gem as

```
gem 'my_engine', git: 'git@github.com:my_engine.git',
                       branch: 'master', revision: 'cb1a8d2495168d411676f58bdfc9015fe728948c'
```

`branch` and `revision` are optional but its recommended if you want to point it to specific commit or branch.

**Make sure the `deploy`(user on server used to deploy application) user has access to engine repository.**